# Multiple ip on an interface with netplan

Tags: networking, server, proxy, netplan

I have a server that uses multiple ip for proxies with Squid.

I'm setting it up on a new server, but with Ubuntu 18 I need to rewrite /etc/network/interfaces for netplan.

On the old server /etc/network/interfaces is like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.2.3.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 1.2.3.0
    broadcast 1.2.3.255
    gateway 1.2.3.254

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 5.6.7.8
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 5.6.7.8
```

It has eth0:1, eth0:2, etc.

Which gives this in ifconfig -a:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:79:37:54
          inet addr:1.2.3.4  Bcast:1.2.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3149890977 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6290843324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1281967559959 (1.2 TB)  TX bytes:7746334018193 (7.7 TB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:79:37:54
          inet addr:5.6.7.8  Bcast:5.6.7.8  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I tried rewriting it different ways in /etc/netplan/conf.yaml, for example like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    prox:
      addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4/24
        - 5.6.7.8/32
      gateway4: 1.2.3.254
```

then run "netplan try" but only 1.2.3.4 appears in ifconfig.

**ip -4 addr list** shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global eno3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Is `prox` an actual interface name?  It looks like the interface name you need to use in your `yaml` is `eno3`...  Try adjusting the yaml config to use `eno3` instead of `prox` and try again.

Comment: Annnnnnd... I feel stupid. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `netplan` config refers to an interface `prox`, which doesn't exist on your system.

Replace it with `eno3` - the actual interface name on the system - and then reapply your `netplan` configs.